# call flock with node.js?

Tags: node.js, flock

I have cron job to run node.js scripts.

Want to use flock to lock a file to make sure my cron jobs are not
overlapped.

Any good module for doing file locking ?

Or I should call that in child process ?

Or I should not do any file locking ?

Sorry, I am new to this and not sure file locking is good for async
env like node. Thanks

Comment: I would just use a child-process because flock is so dead simple... as to whether file locking is good for async really depends on, as it does for most things, how you implement. Just be careful not to block I/O and you should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `flock` function in `fs-ext` package: https://github.com/baudehlo/node-fs-ext

Comment: This is deprecated and can't even be installed in newer version of Node.

Answer (score 8):

If you're just trying to keep cron jobs from overlapping, consider using the "flock" utility in your crontab instead.

If your cron line looks something like this:

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/node /usr/local/share/myscript
```

You can just change it to this:

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/flock -n /var/lock/myscript /usr/bin/node /usr/local/share/myscript
```

This will try to get the lock on the lockfile /var/lock/myscript. If it can, it will run the command on the rest of the line and then release the lock; if not (because there's another job running), it will fail.

This keeps you from having to add a lot of dependencies on 'fs-ext' and so on.

There's more information at http://linux.die.net/man/1/flock

Comment: Inspiration from http://mihasya.com/blog/a-quick-note-on-cron-utilities/ (Credit where credit is due)

Comment: I'm getting this error: `/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: You can also avoid the fork() and unneeded subshell: https://blog.famzah.net/2013/07/31/using-flock-in-bash-without-invoking-a-subshell/

Answer (score 0):

There is also a packet fcf-framework-lock for locking files: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcf-framework-lock

Package feature description page: https://fcf-framework.tech/packages/fcf-framework-lock

```
let lock = require("fcf-framework-lock");
let util = require("util");

async main() {
  // Take the lock
  const lockId = await util.promisify(lock.lockFile)("LOCK_FILE_PATH");

  // ...
  // let's do something
  // ..

  // Free the lock
  await util.promisify(lock.unlockFile)(lockId);
}

main();
```